# Use flutter_local_notifications plugin in Isolate

Tags: flutter

I have some business logic that requires to create a number of scheduled notifications, from 1 to *n* with *n* being defined prior running the code that loops until it reaches *n*. I have to loop from 1 to *n* as I use each count as index to access some elements of a list.

Psuedo code for it is something like:

```
for(int i=1; i<=50; i++){
   // below is a function that calls into an initialized instace of FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin()
   // that I use to access the notification scheduler helper
   createNotification(i);
}
```

Running it seems fine both on my emulator and actual device. However, I found out that running that part of the code on older or weaker-specced device would cause the UI to momentarily be unresponsive or laggy. From my research, I am thinking that the logic and code that I am using is too taxing for the Main Isolate and should be put on a separate one for parallel execution that will free up my Main Isolate to maintain my UI's performance.

Below is the code for the high-level class called by the Flutter *compute* helper for Isolates.

```
test(int _num) async {
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  var android = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
  var iOS = IOSInitializationSettings(
    requestSoundPermission: false,
    requestBadgePermission: false,
    requestAlertPermission: false,
  );
  var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(android, iOS);

  var androidDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'channelId',
    'channelName',
    'channelDescription',
    importance: Importance.Max,
    priority: Priority.High,
  );
  var iOSDetails = IOSNotificationDetails();
  NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(androidDetails, iOSDetails);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings); // Error appears in this part

  int total = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < _num; i++) {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(0, 'title', 'body',
        DateTime.now().add(Duration(seconds: 5)), platformChannelSpecifics);
    total += 1;
  }
}
```

I call the test function like below.

```
await compute(test, 100000000);
```

However, I am having the error below:

```
Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding was initialized.
If you're running an application and need to access the binary messenger before `runApp()` has been called (for example, during plugin initialization), then you need to explicitly call the `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` first.
If you're running a test, you can call the `TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` as the first line in your test's `main()` method to initialize the binding.)
```

I have indeed followed what was in the error message which is also the same recommendation of others by adding a line of code in the main() body of the Flutter app but was not able to make it work as well.

It seems that I cannot access the plugin from the top-level class used for the Isolate. I'm hoping you guys can help or atleast suggest an improvement on what I am currently doing that may help. Thank you!

Comment: [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13937) may be helpful:

Comment: Thank you for your time responding @Ryosuke I'll look into it